# Write OpenCV Mat in 16Bit one channel

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm stuck on writing a OpenCV Mat in `16 Bit`. Whatever I try the result is always an `8 Bit (0-255)` image. I checked for relating questions on SO but nothig here solved this issue.

The Mat contains `0-65535` greyscale values before writing it to disk. I already tried the following (and many more approaches):

```
cv::Mat depth;
depth.convertTo(depth, CV_16UC1);
imwrite("depth.png", depth);
```

as in the documentation for [imwrite()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?#imwrite) they say, that it is possible to save a Mat with imwrite() when it is in `CV_16U`

What is wrong with the code? Anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: The problem is not in saving the image. I think the problem is when you load the image using imread. if you use imread without any flags, then the default option assumes that the image is color image and it tries to load it as 8bit uchar, Try: `cv::imread("DepthInput.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); ` to load the depth image·

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the following work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main( int, char** argv )
{
  // Start with unsigned shorts and write to PNG
  unsigned short data[4] = {0,12000,24000,65535};
  Mat src =  Mat(1,4,CV_16UC1,data);
  imwrite("depth.png",src);

  // Start with floats and convert to 16-bit then write to PNG
  float dataf[4]={0.0,12000.0,25000.0,65000.0};
  Mat a = Mat(1,4,CV_32FC1,dataf);
  a.convertTo(a,CV_16UC1);
  imwrite("d2.png",a);
}
```

I can check them with **ImageMagick** as follows, and both are 16-bit greyscale PNGs:

```
convert depth.png txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4,1,65535,gray
0,0: (0)  #000000000000  gray(0)
1,0: (12000)  #2EE02EE02EE0  gray(18.3108%)
2,0: (24000)  #5DC05DC05DC0  gray(36.6217%)
3,0: (65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFF  gray(255)
```

and

```
convert d2.png txt:

# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 4,1,65535,gray
0,0: (0)  #000000000000  gray(0)
1,0: (12000)  #2EE02EE02EE0  gray(18.3108%)
2,0: (25000)  #61A861A861A8  gray(38.1476%)
3,0: (65000)  #FDE8FDE8FDE8  gray(99.1836%)
```

I suggest your problem is elsewhere. Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Also, maybe try writing it to `FileStorage` or `PGM` format instead of `PNG` and look at the file in a normal editor to see if it really looks like 16-bit data - and if it works at all.

Comment: Thanks Mark, the first suggested approach worked. I will investigate to find out what was wrong with my code and post an Edit.